# Keep gitlab build running after build

Tags: docker, gitlab, odoo, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have gitlab ci running, complete with runners. I can build a docker image, execute commands etc.

But, can I keep the build running to do browse tests?

My final goal is to have an Odoo instance running and have a user browse an odoo instance. Odoo runs a webserver on a port, normally 8069, but it's also possible to run odoo in port 80, maybe with nginx as reverse proxy.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by can you keep the build running. Are you asking if there is a way to have it automatically start when the server starts and to stay started? If so, yes, that is possible. You would want the data persisted to the host or to a linked docker container acting as a data container so that you don't start from scratch each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For that you require to give configuration file when you start odoo.
That file contains.....(name like openerp.conf)

[options]
db_host=localhost
db_port=5432
db_user=openerp
db_password=openerp
xmlrpc_port = 80
addons_path=/odoo/addons/
logfile=/var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log

you can start server like
python openerp-server --conf=/home/user/openerp.conf
```